# It's not entirely my fault, but my boss is only blaming me

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, team-role

I am a junior developer in a software development team. I was recently introduced to this project, so as a rule, my senior would configure the project in my machine (generally I do it on my own), but this project works on a legacy framework, which I am facing for the first time. So, I asked my senior to help me out. Unfortunately, she wasn't capable of configuring it. She said that she will be doing it later.

After some days, when my boss (Team Lead) asked me about the whereabouts of the project, I reported him. After knowing that the project is yet to be configured, he became furious and started insulting me brutally in the office.But, he didn't utter a single word against my senior.

**What does it mean?**

Comment: Sorry I don't agree with your title. It *is* entirely your fault. Although your boss should have exercised restraint. Insulting your team members is not becoming of a manager, more so if it is done publicly (as your description strongly implies).

Comment: As this is my first organization, i tend to believe, that for seniors are responsible in configuring a project, is this not the practice everywhere?... Even i have instances that people of equally experienced (considering year), the person who is more into a project entirely configures the project to the new person. I don't excuse my responsibility, as i must know how things happen.

Comment: "Configuring a project" is not some universally agreed activity. Anyway, it is your responsibility to get the things done that are necessary to do your job. The senior may be the person who *can* do it, but it is still your responsibility to get it done from him. You also seemed to be expecting that your boss should have said something to your senior for not configuring your project, I see no good reason for that.

Comment: I have already acknowledged that in my first comment. What is the point you are trying to make?

Comment: Does the team your part of work using some sort of agile methodology ? If yes, then a daily stand-up meeting is probably part of that methodology. What did you say during those meetings ?

Comment: Sorry, no agile methodology@RaduMurzea

Comment: So you haven't done *any* work during those days?

Comment: I was going through the KT videos and the documents provided to me@Lilienthal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does it mean?

It means that you were given a task and didn't bother to see the big picture i.e. the impact of failing to make progress on your task on your team. You missed the fact that your being a junior professional does not excuse you from having any responsibility and accountability. In fact, your level of responsibility and accountability for the management of any task you've been given ownership is 100%.

1. As of now, you still have no idea what the priority and urgency levels of your task are. Whatever the levels are, they seem to be pretty high.
2. The failure of your senior to follow up on her pledge to configure your machine for the project created a delay - a delay which you failed to keep your boss informed. It's your responsibility to keep your management and your colleagues in the loop as to whatever progress and especially, lack of progress, you are making in the execution of your tasks.
3. You are responsible for the management of your own tasks. If something is impacting your progress in finishing your tasks and that something is out of your control, you have to escalate to your seniors and to your management. You cannot go into radio silence for days on end without volunteering info that may be vital to the effective management of the team.
4. Regardless of how much assistance and support you are successful in getting from other people such as your senior, you still own accountability and responsibility for the completion of your tasks (s). This means that you have to be up to date at all times regarding the status of your tasks including degree of completion, current levels of priority and urgency - and that you are able, willing and ready to report on this status at all times to your management and seniors. And you have to keep your management and seniors informed on a timely basis. Manage by exception - your management and seniors are not likely to crack down on you on anything that's okay, they are much more likely to be concerned about anything that you're responsible and accountable for that's going South. If things are going South, don't wait until they are at point South before you inform them.
5. You are not coming across as a professional. Professionals build a reputation for reliability when they keep the people they impact in the loop. On a proactive basis.
6. You are a member of the team. You don't work alone. You need to coordinate with others. Just because you are given individual tasks does not mean that you are excused from being a member of the team let alone acting as a member of the team.

What you need to do next:

1. Report to your senior that the team lead cracked down on you. You need to escalate the priority and urgency levels she is putting on her task of configuring the machine. Inform the team lead that you are ready to go when you're satisfied that your machine is configured. Don't wait for the team lead to ask you again.
2. Make sure that you are up to date with respect to knowing the priority and urgency levels of every task that you own. And its deadline.
3. In the future, make sure that you keep your seniors and your management informed. On a timely basis if you can't do it on a proactive basis. When it comes to reporting, manage by exception.
4. You say that the team leader tore you a new one. His ranting aside, did you pay attention to anything he said?

Comment: Will keep that in mind...It's just that it hurts...But, in a professional area, i tend to be professional. That's the key

Comment: @Arka_Dev - Everything is temporary, everything comes and goes including hurt and including unhappiness. Right now, you are feeling hurt and unhappiness but they will go away :) And come back. And go away, etc. The important part is that you are resilient and that you learn how to be resilient in the face of hurt and unhappiness. I learned decades ago not to get emotionally involved with my problems and how to view any suffering of mine with detachment. I take the attitude that I am not the center of the universe so if something bad happens to me, I don't give a shit. The world still goes on.

Comment: @Arka_Dev "Shit happens, move on" is a piece of advice I commonly give (especially to myself), and it suits your situation perfectly.

Comment: @Arka_Dev - Live it. Learn it. Put it behind you. And go forward without looking back :)